# Windows - Copying files to multiple computers

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

I have several virtual machines (all running windows) based on different servers. I need to copy some files to all these computers. I have admin userid and passwords for all these machines. Some times I need to execute a silent installers on these machines. Is there a tool that I can use to do this job?

Comment: Show us your code you have already.

Comment: what code? I am not talking about a script. I am asking if there is any tool to copy files to remote machines.

Answer (score 3):

I've copied things to the remote servers via the default administrator share (\server\c$), and used PsExec. Check it out:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

I think rcmd and rcmdsvc are in the Windows server resource kit, though I'm not sure about more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest there are quite literally hundreds, maybe tens, of ways of doing this.

Personally I would use a simple batch file that maps a network drive (net use) and then copies the files.  Rather than copy or xcopy I would recommend using robocopy as this support functions such as mirroring.

As for executing installers, thats a different question entirely.  For this you could use remote command (rcmd) to execute the installer once you have copied it across.